# Is there a general formula for range of complex inversion map?

Tags: complex-analysis

The map $z\mapsto 1/z$ has a nice mapping property. That is, it takes a circle $|z-\alpha|=|\alpha|$ to a straight line in a complex plane. Is there a formula for this line?

Moreover, when considering Riemann sphere, is the map $z\mapsto 1/z$ defined to be $\infty$ at $0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the map $f(z) = 1/z$ extends to the Riemann sphere by $f(\infty) = 0$ as you suspect.

To find an equation for the line you're looking for, take two points $z_1$ and $z_2$ on the circle (but not $z=0$) and compute $f(z_1)$ and $f(z_2)$. The line will be the one connecting these points. Choose $z_1$ and $z_2$ cleverly to minimize the amount of calculations you need to do.

Comment: The function $f$ itself is undefined at $0$. Is it defined to have $\infty$ at 0?

Comment: @John.p: Yes, that's right.